# Find unused labels

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

Is there any way I can find labels which are not used in D365 FO (labels which dont have references)?

Answer (score 3):

The cross references are stored in database `DYNAMICSXREFDB`. You can use a [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) query to generate a list of labels that have no references.

This query uses two tables in the database:

- `Names` holds an entry for each object in the application that can be referenced.

  - The `Path` field of the table holds the name of the object (e.g. `/Labels/@FormRunConfiguration:ViewDefaultLabel` is the path of the `ViewDefaultLabel` in the `FormRunConfiguration` label file.
  - Field `Id` is used to reference a record in this table in other tables.
- `References` holds the actual references that connect the objects.

  - Field `SourceId` contains the `Id` of the `Names` record of the object that references another object identified by field `TargetId`.

The actual query could look like this:

```sql
SELECT LabelObjects.Path AS UnusedLabel 
FROM [dbo].[Names] AS LabelObjects
WHERE LabelObjects.Path LIKE '/Labels/%' 
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * 
        FROM [dbo].[References] AS LabelReferences 
        WHERE LabelReferences.TargetId = LabelObjects.Id)
```

Make sure to compile the application to update the cross reference data. Otherwise the query might give you wrong results. When I run this query on a version 10.0.3 PU27 environment, it returns one standard label as a result.

[image: ResultOfQueryForUnusedLabels]